# Why must I use sudo for ssh public key authentication to work?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, ssh, authentication

I cannot ssh from my computer (OS X) to my raspberry pi (ubuntu mate), unless I use sudo. I am using a public/private keypair to authenticate.

The appropriate public key is added to the authorized_users file on the raspberry pi.

The permissions for my .ssh directory are 700.
The permissions for my key files are 600.

This is the output from ssh with -v flag:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey 
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try. Permission denied (publickey).
```

ls:

```
-rw------- 1 username staff 3326 May 18 23:24 id_rsa 
-rw-r--r-- 1 username staff 752 May 18 23:24 id_rsa.pub
```

.ssh:

```
drwx------  11 username   staff    374 May 19 21:49 .ssh
```

Comment: Have you checked that `username` definitely owns `.ssh` and its contents?

Comment: @Paul Yes the appropriate user owns the .ssh directory and its contents

Comment: And the .ssh directory itself?  Please [edit] if you have more infomation to add to the question

Comment: @Paul, added .ssh information

Comment: Hang on, when you do sudo it uses the root .ssh directory.  What username are you logging into the rpi with?

Comment: @Paul, you're onto something here.  Explicitly stating the username causes permission denied (public key), even when using sudo.  It seems it's an issue with my setup on the raspberry pi, then.

Comment: Yeah, you must be logging in a root remotely when you use sudo, so the problem probably lies in the authorized_keys of `username`

Answer (score 1):

You probably shared root's ssh key, perhaps by doing `sudo` when you did `ssh-copy-id`.  Make sure `username`'s public key is also in the `authorized_keys` on the destination

Comment: the key in authorized_users is identical to my non-root public key

Comment: So if you do, say, `md5sum` on both `id_rsa.pub` and `authorized_keys` they're the same?  (assuming you have only the one key in authorized_keys.  Presumably if it works with sudo it should also match the `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file, so are all 3 the same?

Comment: there are multiple keys in authorized_key.  I believe the issue is that I am logging in against the root on my raspberry pi when I want to be logging in as a specific user.  I'm going to physically access the machine and check the user's authorized_key file

Comment: Ah, well when you do `sudo` your default user to connect as will be root instead of `username`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a disconnect here. You keep saying authorized_users; others keep saying authorized_keys.
The public key for a user is put into the home directory for the user in a file called .ssh/authorized_keys, not .ssh/authorized_users. Since ssh is working for root, you might want to look at the directory for ~root/.ssh and make the directory for ~user_name/.ssh look the same - except, of course, that the keys will be the ones for that user, not for root.

Comment: Thanks, the authorized_users/authorized_keys thing was simply me typing the wrong name.  The issue turned out to be that root owned the /etc/ssh directory, rather than username.  I fixed that and everything appears to be working properly

Comment: A user should never own any files in the /etc directory. They need read and execute permission for /etc/ssh and read access to most of the files in the directory, the exceptions being the private key files and the sshd files. If the user owns a file in /etc they can give themselves write permission and affect every other user on the system including root.